# Add Text into Alertview textfield iOS

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uialertview

When the alert view shows up I want to have existing text already within the textfield. This is my code, what must I add?

```
        UIAlertView* dialog = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Add", nil];
        [dialog setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput];

        // Change keyboard type
        [[dialog textFieldAtIndex:0] setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeDefault];

        [dialog show];
```

Comment: Curious - If you knew how to set the text field's keyboard type, why couldn't you figure out how to set the text field's text?

Comment: I knew there must be some sort of setText function but since my formatting was incorrect it never came up when the function list populates

Comment: I think its a great question to have up and its the first to be asked on stackoverflow

Comment: I made no comment about the question. And this isn't the first question. It's nearly the 7 millionth question on SO. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UIAlertView* dialog = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Add", nil];
[dialog setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput];
[[dialog textFieldAtIndex:0] setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeDefault];

[[dialog textFieldAtIndex:0]setText:@"Your string here"];

[dialog show];
```

Comment: No problem, it won't allow me to accept for another 10 minutes but I will immediately after

Answer (score 1):

```
UIAlertView* dialog = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Add", nil];
        [dialog setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput];
[[dialog textFieldAtIndex:0]setText:@"YourText"];
        // Change keyboard type
        [[dialog textFieldAtIndex:0] setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeDefault];

        [dialog show];
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm taking a shot in the dark here, but try 
        dialog.textfield.text = @"Blah blahddy blah"
Put it before `[dialog show]`.

Comment: Don't take shots in the dark. If you don't know the answer, don't post a random (and incorrect) guess.

Comment: BTW - feel free to delete your answer to get your reputation points back.

Comment: Why would someone up vote this answer? Don't needlessly reward people for posting wrong answers.